# How can I pass user id into a serializer with request data?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a project that autenticate by `oauth2_provider.ext.rest_framework.OAuth2Authentication`. There is a token in the request headers for authenticating and identifying. I think I should not include user id in the request data explicitly when process a create action. But serializer need user info to create a new instance. So I include a user_id field in serializer, and put the value into the `request.data` dict after authenticating.

Is it good? Is there any better way?

serializers.py

```
class serializer(serializers.Serializer):
    user = UserSerializer(read_only=True)
    user_id = serializers.UUIDField(write_only=True)
    content = serializers.CharField()
```

views.py

```
class CommentList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        request.data['user_id'] = request.user.id
        return super(CommentList, self).create(request)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is cleaner to override `create(validated_data)` in your serializer:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    ...

    def create(self, validated_data):
      user = self.context['request'].user
      comment = Comment.objects.create(
         user=user, 
         **validated_data
      )
      return comment
```

See http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances

Then you do not need to customise your view, you can just use a generic view.

Comment: I think `self.request.user` in Serializer should be `self.context['request'].user`

Comment: I am getting this error: "TypeError: create() got multiple values for keyword argument 'user'". Seems like validated_data also contains the field user. How can you overcome this ?

Comment: @Twimnox `user` field is really `read_only` in your serializer ? 
If `validated_data` still contains user field, you can override user value in validated_data : `validated_data['user'] = user`, then remove user kwarg from create call.

Comment: @pchiquet I don't think this is the right way to do

Comment: @pchiquet `Django` throws an error with `self.context['request'].user`

Comment: @AzharUddinSheikh you must pass a request in serializer context, see https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context, DRF does this for you behind the scene if you let its generic views instanciate the serializer for you.

Comment: CurrentUserDefault has been added in recent DRF versions https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#currentuserdefault (same thing, more generic)

Answer (score 2):

if user is `authenticated` then grab the value from `request` object and pass it to `serializers` by using `get_serializer_context` method

```
class CommentList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    
    def get_serializer_context(self):
        return {'user_id':self.request.user.id}

 class serializer(serializers.Serializer):
     #your field, model
     pass
     
     def create(self, validated_data):
         user_id = self.context['user_id']
         return Comment.objects.create(user_id=user_id, **validated_data)
```